# Where are 'comments' on files/folders under KDE stored?

Tags: kde

Under KDE, I can add 'comments' to any File/folder. Where is all this data stored?

Comment: Follow up with this: [Unity/Gnome equivalent to the feature](http://askubuntu.com/q/153221/45659)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE userbase - Nepomuk: http://userbase.kde.org/Nepomuk

> ...The information sidebar of Dolphin (View -> Panels -> Information,
>   or press F11) presents information extracted by Strigi about the
>   selected file, and also allows you to assign tags, ratings and
>   comments to files. This information is then stored in Nepomuk...

Nepomuk data: ~/.kde/share/apps/nepomuk/...

Comment: That kind of explains why nepomuk got auto-installed as dependency. :)